# Get variable from JSON output with special character in object name

Tags: php, arrays, json

I cannot find how to get the results from this JSON post in PHP.

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [api_job_id] => 398438bf-c0a5-46fc-8774-70d2425e1ce7
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => MESSAGE
                    [message_id] => 15125005817130024103
                    [to] => xxx
                    [error_code] => 0
                    [#meta] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [error] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [error_desc] => NO_USER
                                    [error_code] => 9
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

as you can see the meta has a # icon before it.

I can read all data to vars instead of the data in the #meta

I tried many ways like:
$result = $arrayResponse['#meta']['error']['error_desc'];
it's not working in PHP because of the # icon.

Any idea how I can get the values from these errors in #meta?

Comment: Can you post what you have come up with? it will help us better understand what you may be missing

Answer (score 2):

To refer to an object attribute with a name that doesn't make a valid variable, you can use braces:

```
$foo = json_decode($string);
var_dump($foo->{'#meta'});
```

Or pass a truthy value to json_decode() as the second argument, and you'll get back an array instead of an object:

```
$foo = json_decode($string, true);
var_dump($foo['#meta']);
```